# How often will reputation of a user be a prime number in this model?

Tags: probability, prime-numbers, expectation

Suppose that user receives reputation only by upvotes and downvotes of her/his question and that for every upvote she/he can have either $0$ or $1$ or $2$ downvotes, with equal probability, equal to $\dfrac {1}{3}$. Also, suppose that downvotes can only be received after an upovote had been received, so that reputation is strictly increasing by $5$, $3$ or $1$ points at every step.

> How many prime numbers (as the score of the reputation) are expected (on average) until the reputation is $\geq 100 000$?

Comment: Seems like a simulation problem.

Comment: Are you considering "steps" (beginning at $1$?) that result from the net addition and subtraction of an upvote and corresponding downvotes (per your probabilistic model), or should intermediate values of reputation between upvotes and downvotes be considered?

Comment: @hardmath In this model, downvotes can only be received after an upvote, with a total of 0, 1 or 2 of them, So, the reputation in this model is strictly increasing.

Comment: I made an edit to be more clear and precise.

Comment: Strictly increasing?  If I currently have $5$ and I get an upvote followed by $2$ downvotes...what is my final reputation?

Comment: @lulu 5+5-2-2=6?

Comment: Ah, I thought you were just counting votes received, so it would be $5+1-2=4$.  This is somewhat confusing.  I'd drop the voting stuff and say "someone starts with a score of $0$ and, at each turn, adds $1,3,5$ to their current score with equal probability."

Comment: Perhaps more to the point, if a user has 12 points and get one upvote followed by a downvote, are they considered to have hit the prime 17?

Comment: @HenningMakholm No, but 12+5-2=15

Comment: As you can see from the comments, nobody can follow the voting stuff.  If I have the rules correctly (big "if"!) then I think my formulation is a lot cleaner.

Comment: As there are no loops you can recursively compute the probability that you land on any specified integer $n$.  That is $P(n)=\frac 13 \times \left(P(n-1)+P(n-3)+P(n-5) \right)$  You can then sum $P(n)$ over prime $n$.

Comment: A quick run (so quick there might have been bugs) shows that $P(n)$ approaches $\frac 13$ quite quickly.  so the answer is, roughly, one third the number of primes in the region.  I would check that carefully, though (and there is some static around small primes).

Comment: @lulu: Yes, it should converge to 1/3. Intuitively this is because for each number we _hit_ we have just _skipped_ either 0, 2, or 4 numbers with equal probability, averaging 2 skipped numbers for each hit number.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  Oh, for sure.  The only questions are:  A.  Have I understood the rules correctly (not even remotely clear) and B. How significant is the ramping period before $P(n)\approx \frac 13$?

Comment: @lulu: The roots of $x^5-\frac13x^4-\frac13x^2-\frac13$ other than $1$ have magnitudes $0.74$ and $0.78$ which tells us how quickly the transient ought to fall off. $\log_{10}(0.78)$ is about $-0.1$, so I would expect $P(10k)$ to approach $0.333\ldots$ to about $k$ significant digits (or better). Does that match your results?

Comment: @HenningMakholm  Oh, my convergence is faster.  I have $P(100)\approx 0.333333333325806$  for instance and even $P(31)\approx 0.333179745179084$.  That speed surprised me a bit, but I don't see any problem in the code.

Comment: @lulu: That seems to match my prediction pretty well, actually.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  Oh, I read your comment incorrectly.  Yes, it is matching extremely well.  Pretty sure it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

As clarified the reputation advances with each upvoted question by $1,3,$ or $5$ with equal chances.

An exact computation is possible using the linearity of expectation.

That is, the expected number of primes below (say) $100,000$ that will be "hit" by a reputation "trajectory" is simply the sum of probabilities of hitting for each such prime.

As Comments by Henning Makholm and lulu explain, the probability of *any* particular number being hit approaches one-third fairly quickly.  So a decent approximation to the expected number of primes occurring in the reputation history is one-third of these primes, e.g. roughly $\pi(10^5)/3 = 9592/3$ before reputation passes $100,000$.

Comment: [My age in years will be prime and so will that of my friend who's age differs by 12 years. If we both live to 1000 roughly how often will this happen?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4381702/284619)